# PyCharm: attach console to debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

In PyCharm, it is possible to attach a debugger to an interactive console session run in PyCharm.

Is it possible to do the opposite? That means: attach an interactive console to a program paused at a debugging breakpoint so that I can issue interactive commands that work with the current debugging context.

Comment: Have you played around with the the expression evaluation window (Alt-F8 when in debug mode) ?

Comment: @idjaw Yes, but that is not what I am looking for. I would like to use the real console. The expression evaluation window is useful only for evaluating expression. Any more complex manipulation becomes very unconvenient.

Comment: What about [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-debug-console.html?origin=old_help) . You can even enable soft wraps to help write out more more complex code.

Comment: @idjaw Wow, didn't know about that. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it as it is exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the interactive shell available during your debugging by using the "Console" tab per what is explained in the PyCharm doc [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-debug-console.html?origin=old_help)

When you access the 'Console' tab, be sure to enable the "Show Python Prompt" and "Enable Soft Wraps".